# Apache Tomcat not working

Tags: centos, java, tomcat

I  have CentOS 6.4 installed on VMware. Recently installed Java SE8 and Apache Tomcat server but I cant't connect to the server by using `localhost:8080' browser says Unable to Connect. I have also tried changing the connector port in the tomcat server config but still unable to connect.

**etc/profile**

```
PATH=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0/bin:$PATH
JRE_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0/jre/bin
CATALINA_HOME=/media/new/softwares/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.5/

export PATH
export JRE_HOME
export CATALINA_HOME
```

**host file**

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

**terminal on starting Tomcat**

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /media/new/softwares/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.5
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /media/new/softwares/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.5
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /media/new/softwares/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.5/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/local/jdk1.8.0/jre/bin
Using CLASSPATH:       /media/new/softwares/Tomcat/apache-tomcat 8.0.5/bin/bootstrap.jar:/media/new/softwares/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.5/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
```

**tomcat's log**

```
/media/new/softwares/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.5/bin/catalina.sh: line 399: /usr/local/jdk1.8.0/jre/bin/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems pretty cut and dry. You don't have Java installed. Or at least it isn't in the location that Tomcat is looking.

> /media/new/softwares/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.5/bin/catalina.sh: line 399: /usr/local/jdk1.8.0/jre/bin/bin/java: No such file or directory

You'll need to to go `www.java.com` and download JDK 1.8.0 or some version of Java  and install it to `/usr/local/...` and then change the configurations around in Tomcat so that it can find Java.

Comment: I have java installed command `java -version` shows `java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)`. Can you tell me how to change Tomcat configuration to let it find java

Comment: Try setting the variable `$JDK_HOME`, and exporting it similar to the other variables.

Answer (score 0):

This path of JDK exist? Give more information about this JDK if you see this error message :

```
/usr/local/jdk1.8.0/jre/**bin/bin**/java
```

There are two /bin/bin maybe this is the error. If jdk exists, try to use this config:

```
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/local/jdk1.8.0/jre
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same problem and found that is was because catalina.sh not figure out jre path. So solved by setting following path variables :

export JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_25"

export JRE_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_25/jre

Answer (score -1):

You should set `JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0` or `JRE_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0/jre`